# Wrote an errback for my Scrapy spider, but tracebacks also keep happening, why?

Tags: scrapy, python-3.5

I am using Scrapy 1.1 and I call Scrapy from within a script. My spider launching method looks like this:

```
def run_spider(self):
    runner = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
    spider = SiteSpider()
    configure_logging()
    d = runner.crawl(spider, websites_file=self.raw_data_file)
    d.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())
    reactor.run()
```

Here is an extract of my spider with an errback written as in the documentation, but it only prints when catches a failure.

```
class SiteSpider(scrapy.Spider):

name = 'SiteCrawler'

custom_settings = {
    'FEED_FORMAT': 'json',
    'FEED_URI': 'result.json',
}

def __init__(self, websites_file=None, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.websites_file = websites_file
    print('***********')
    print(self.websites_file)

def start_requests(self):
     .....
            if is_valid_url(website_url):
                yield scrapy.Request(url=website_url, callback=self.parse, errback=self.handle_errors, meta={'url': account_id})

def parse(self, response):
    .....
        yield item

def handle_errors(self, failure):
    if failure.check(HttpError):
        # these exceptions come from HttpError spider middleware
        # you can get the non-200 response
        response = failure.value.response
        print('HttpError on ' + response.url)

    elif failure.check(DNSLookupError):
        # this is the original request
        request = failure.request
        print('DNSLookupError on ' + request.url)

    elif failure.check(TimeoutError, TCPTimedOutError):
        request = failure.request
        print('TimeoutError on ' + request.url)
```

My problem is that I get errors I expect, like:

```
TimeoutError on http://www.example.com
```

But also get tracebacks for the same websites:

```
2016-08-05 13:40:55 [scrapy] ERROR: Error downloading <GET http://www.example.com/robots.txt>: TCP connection timed out: 60: Operation timed out.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1126, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)
  File ".../anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/twisted/python/failure.py", line 389, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
    return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
  File ".../anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/middleware.py", line 43, in process_request
    defer.returnValue((yield download_func(request=request,spider=spider)))
twisted.internet.error.TCPTimedOutError: TCP connection timed out: 60: Operation timed out.
```

The written exception handling messages and the tracebacks can often be traced to the same websites. After searching a lot on stackoverflow, in the docs and the likes I still dont know why I see the tracebacks.
This also occurs with DNSLookupErrors for example.
Excuse me, my Scrapy knowledge is juvenile. Is this normal behavior?

Also, I added this to settings.py, which is under my crawler. Other entires (for example the item_pipelines) most exactly work.

```
LOG_LEVEL = 'WARNING'
```

But I still see debug messages, not only warnings and everything above that. (if configure_logging() is added to the spider launch) I am running this from terminal on mac os x.
I would be very happy to get any help with this.

Comment: How you fixed this timeout issue?

Answer (score -1):

Try this in a script:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    runner = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
    spider = SiteSpider()
    configure_logging()
    d = runner.crawl(spider, websites_file=self.raw_data_file)
    d.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())
    reactor.run()
```